# new Twilio(accountSid, authToken) gives "Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword" Error

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I was upgrading Twilio node from 2.x to 3.x with [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node/migration-guide) guide.Twilio's current version in my system is 3.6.3 and typings for Twilio(@types/twilio) is 0.0.9.I have imported twilio in my code as

```
import * as Twilio from "twilio";
```

In 2.x,new instance of Twilio was created as

```
const twilio=new Twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);
```

However this does not work in 3.x. When I console logged twilio nothing gets printed and also Iam not getting any error.As mentioned in tutorial,I tried using

```
const twilio=new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
```

This shows the following error,

```
 Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272730/var-client-new-twilio-restclienttest-1-test-2) with no answer.
Is this problem because typings of Twilio(@types/twilio) is not updated to support version 3.x?(Iam also unable to find method **fetch()** in typings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is because the typings for Twilio (@types/twilio version:0.09) is not compatible with Twilio 3.x.

Feature Request for typings for Twilio 3.x :- https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/250

Related Issue:- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18992